# Make Parallel.ForEach wait to get work until a slot opens

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, parallel-processing

I'm using `Parallel.ForEach` to work a bunch of items. The problem is, I want to prioritize which items get worked depending on the number of workers (slots) that are open. E.g. if I am working 8 parallel things and a slot opens between task 1-4, I want to assign easy work to those slots. The bottom half of the slots will get the hard work. This way, I won't get all 8 slots tied up doing hard/long-running work, easy/quick items will be run first. I've implemented this as follows:

**The Code**

```
const int workers = 8;
List<Thing> thingsToDo = ...; //Get the things that need to be done.
Thing[] currentlyWorkingThings = new Thing[workers]; //One slot for each worker.

void Run() {
    Parallel.ForEach(PrioritizeThings(thingsToDo), o => {
        int index = 0;

        //"PrioritizeTasks" added this thing to the list of currentlyWorkingThings.
        //Find my position in this list.
        lock (currentlyWorkingThings)
            index = currentlyWorkingThings.IndexOf(o);

        //Do work on this thing...

        //Then remove it from the list of currently working things, thereby
        //  opening a new slot when this worker returns/finishes.
        lock (currentlyWorkingThings)
            currentlyWorkingThings[index] = null;
    });
}

IEnumerable<Thing> PrioritizeThings(List<Thing> thingsToDo) {
    int slots = workers;
    int halfSlots = (int)Math.Ceiling(slots / 2f);

    //Sort thingsToDo by their difficulty, easiest first.

    //Loop until we've worked every Thing.
    while (thingsToDo.Count > 0) {
        int slotToFill = ...; //Find the first open slot.
        Thing nextThing = null;

        lock (currentlyWorkingThings) {
            //If the slot is in the "top half", get the next easy thing - otherwise
            //  get the next hard thing.
            if (slotToFill < halfSlots)
                nextThing = thingsToDo.First();
            else
                nextThing = thingsToDo.Last();

            //Add the nextThing to the list of currentlyWorkingThings and remove it from
            //  the list of thingsToDo.
            currentlyWorkingThings[slotToFill] = nextThing;
            thingsToDo.Remove(nextThing);
        }

        //Return the nextThing to work.
        yield return nextThing;
    }
}
```

**The Problem**

So the issue I'm seeing here is that `Parallel` is requesting the next thing to work on from `PrioritizeThings` before a slot has opened (before an existing thing has been completed). I assume that `Parallel` is looking ahead and getting things to work ready in advance. I'd like it to not do this, and only fill a worker/slot when it is completely done. The only way I've thought of to fix this is to add a sleep/wait loop in `PrioritizeThings` which won't return a thing to work until it sees a legitimate open slot. But I don't like that and I was hoping that there was some way to make `Parallel` wait longer before getting work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could keep a list of the 8 (plus 1 pending) things being worked on.  If you have less than 4 complex tasks, give it a complex task else give it an easy task. The longest you'd have an imbalance would be until the quickest easy task is completed.

Comment: @Jesse I think that's what I'll have to do. Only give `Parallel` 8 items to work to begin with and then put that inside a while look that runs until all items have been worked in 8-item chunks (or however many workers there are). Not sure if that's what you were suggesting but that's what I thought of when reading your comment.

Comment: (Thinking out loud.) I can't do what I just suggested since then new items won't be worked until all 8 of the current items finish. Doh! @Jesse - if you want to clarify what you meant, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I was thinking keep track of what items are being worked on, when it asks for something new you have to decide, give it something hard or easy.  If there are already four hard tasks then give it an easy one.  There's always a possibility the task finishing is a hard one and you'll have 5 easy and 3 hard but only for the small amount of time until the next task finishes, then you can fill the hard tasks back up to 4.

Comment: @Jesse, that's what the code I posted does. But the problem is that `Parallel` seems to ask for more work than it can do at any given time. (E.g. before a slot is actually open, so I can't determine which type of work to give it - easy or hard.)

Comment: Have you looked into the `ParallelOptions` class?  Maybe if you set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` field on that class to 8, and use that overload of `Parallel.ForEach()` that might work.

Comment: @Jesse - yes, I am already doing what you suggest but it still seems to "look ahead".

Comment: Have you looked into `BlockingCollection<T>` in `System.Collections.Concurrent`? They are really neat for efficiently 'waiting' for work units to come down. Also check out [MSDN: ConcurrentPriorityQueue.cs](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364/sourcecode?fileId=44488&pathId=1696822056)

Comment: That's my point, < 4 hard, supply hard, else supply easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way built in (kinda) to support exactly the situation you are describing.

When you create the `ForEach` you will need to pass in a [`ParallelOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a non-standard [`TaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.taskscheduler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The hard part is creating a `TaskSchedueler` to do that priority system for you, fortunately Microsoft released a pack of examples that contains one such scheduler called "[ParallelExtensionsExtras](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/04/9990342.aspx)" with its scheduler [`QueuedTaskScheduler`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx)

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int totalMaxConcurrancy = Environment.ProcessorCount;
    int highPriorityMaxConcurrancy = totalMaxConcurrancy / 2;

    if (highPriorityMaxConcurrancy == 0)
        highPriorityMaxConcurrancy = 1;

    QueuedTaskScheduler qts = new QueuedTaskScheduler(TaskScheduler.Default, totalMaxConcurrancy);
    var highPriortiyScheduler = qts.ActivateNewQueue(0);
    var lowPriorityScheduler = qts.ActivateNewQueue(1);

    BlockingCollection<Foo> highPriorityWork = new BlockingCollection<Foo>();
    BlockingCollection<Foo> lowPriorityWork = new BlockingCollection<Foo>();

    List<Task> processors = new List<Task>(2);

    processors.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(highPriorityWork.GetConsumingPartitioner(),  //.GetConsumingPartitioner() is also from ParallelExtensionExtras, it gives better performance than .GetConsumingEnumerable() with Parallel.ForEeach(
                         new ParallelOptions() { TaskScheduler = highPriortiyScheduler, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = highPriorityMaxConcurrancy }, 
                         ProcessWork);
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));

    processors.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(lowPriorityWork.GetConsumingPartitioner(), 
                         new ParallelOptions() { TaskScheduler = lowPriorityScheduler}, 
                         ProcessWork);
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));


    //Add some work to do here to the highPriorityWork or lowPriorityWork collections


    //Lets the blocking collections know we are no-longer going to be adding new items so it will break out of the `ForEach` once it has finished the pending work.
    highPriorityWork.CompleteAdding();
    lowPriorityWork.CompleteAdding();

    //Waits for the two collections to compleatly empty before continueing
    Task.WaitAll(processors.ToArray());
}

private static void ProcessWork(Foo work)
{
    //...
}
```

Even though you have two instances of `Parallel.ForEach` running the combined total of both of them will not use more than the value you passed in for `MaxConcurrency` in to the `QueuedTaskScheduler` constructor and it will give preference to emptying the `highPriorityWork` collection first if there is work to do in both (up to a limit of 1/2 of all of the available slots so that you don't choke the low priority queue, you could easily adjust this to be a higher or lower ratio depending on your performance needs).

If you don't want the high priority to always win and you rather have a "round-robin" style scheduler that alternates between the two lists (so you don't want the quick items to always win, but just have them shuffled in with the slow items) you can set the same priority level to two or more queues (or just use the `RoundRobinTaskSchedulerQueue` which does the same thing)

Comment: Interesting. If all of the things to do in the highPriorityScheduler finish, will the lowPriorityScheduler then fill those extra slots with low priority itesm? E.g. I wouldn't want the easy stuff to finish and then 4 slots are left idle while the hard stuff has a long queue.

Comment: Yes, it will. The one thing I may recommend is change the high priority `ParallelOptions` to be `{ TaskScheduler = highPriortiyScheduler, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }` if you don't if you have a consistent stream of high priority items you will never process low priority items. By adding that constraint to the foreach the high priority foreach will process `0-4` items at once and the low priority will process `0-8` items at once but will give up slots to the high priority one if work comes in to that queue.

Comment: I have updated the code example to show what I was just talking about. The one drawback is if the hard stuff finishes the easy stuff will only use up to 4 cores to process. If you are not concerned about the hard work getting choked you can remove the constraint, or perhaps change it to a more extreme ratio like `totalMaxConcurrancy - 1`

Comment: The other option is to split the list into two, pre-sorted by difficulty so list1 has easy stuff, list2 has hard stuff, and then keep the priorities the same. That should cause each `Parallel` to use 4 cores until one finishes and then the other will use 8 cores.

Comment: That is what I was trying to describe in the last paragraph.

Comment: Although I ended up simplifying my solution and just doing the easy work first, I think this solution would have worked as well. Thanks.