# Synchronizing heavy and light tasks in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, task

I am trying to implement some kind of task queue with different task weights allowing different amount of tasks to run concurrently based on their weights.

There are two types of tasks: long task and short task.
Maximum of N short tasks can be executed together.

When the long task appears, it should start immediately if there are no other long task running or wait for it to complete otherwise.

Concurrent short task count limit should be reduced to M if there is long task running.
Short tasks running already should keep running to completion; but no new short tasks should start if the current limit is less or equal than current running short tasks amount.

As it seems, I basically need the ability to dynamically change semaphore "capacity".
It would be easy to decrease/increase the capacity by just taking/freeing (N - M) "slots" when needed, but that would cause "hanging" of the queue before (N - M) short tasks complete  if there are N short tasks already running.

I could also implement some kind of "scheduler" awaking every 100 ms (for example) and checking the queue for any tasks that can start now. Disadvantage of this approach is having up to 100 ms delay between enqueueing the task and starting it.

So I am stuck with that puzzle and hope that someone will have some fresh idea about how to implement this.

**Update:**
Tasks are not going to create any significant CPU load. 
They are HTTP requests in fact. Long requests are uploading files and short requests are common HTTP requests.

Comment: If you are not looking to re-invent the wheel and using .NET 4.5 you can use the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) (Task Parallel Library) and [Task Schedulers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I would like to not re-invent the wheel.
But it does not seem that TaskScheduler can help me with the thing I'm trying to achieve. Or may be I am missing something?

Comment: I've updated the question to add some more details about the nature of the tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a very similar question [a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195406/make-parallel-foreach-wait-to-get-work-until-a-slot-opens/21196248#21196248), the solution for you is pretty much the exact same, use  [`QueuedTaskScheduler`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx)
 from "[ParallelExtensionsExtras](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/04/9990342.aspx)"

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int highPriorityMaxConcurrancy = 1

    QueuedTaskScheduler qts = new QueuedTaskScheduler();
    var highPriortiyScheduler = qts.ActivateNewQueue(0);
    var lowPriorityScheduler = qts.ActivateNewQueue(1);

    BlockingCollection<HttpRequestWrapper> fileRequest= new BlockingCollection<Foo>();
    BlockingCollection<HttpRequestWrapper> commonRequest= new BlockingCollection<Foo>();

    List<Task> processors = new List<Task>(2);

    processors.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(fileRequest.GetConsumingPartitioner(),  //.GetConsumingPartitioner() is also from ParallelExtensionExtras, it gives better performance than .GetConsumingEnumerable() with Parallel.ForEeach(
                         new ParallelOptions() { TaskScheduler = highPriortiyScheduler, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = highPriorityMaxConcurrancy }, 
                         ProcessWork);
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));

    processors.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(commonRequest.GetConsumingPartitioner(), 
                         new ParallelOptions() { TaskScheduler = lowPriorityScheduler}, 
                         ProcessWork);
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));


    //Add some work to do here to the fileRequest or commonRequest collections


    //Lets the blocking collections know we are no-longer going to be adding new items so it will break out of the `ForEach` once it has finished the pending work.
    fileRequest.CompleteAdding();
    commonRequest.CompleteAdding();

    //Waits for the two collections to compleatly empty before continueing
    Task.WaitAll(processors.ToArray());
}

private static void ProcessWork(HttpRequestWrapper request)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to also pass IProgress for long tasks and CancellationToken for all tasks? I guess I can pass them as HttpRequestWrapper members and use them in ProcessWork?
Also, won't Task.WaitAll(processors.ToArray()) stop automatically if there are no tasks to run?
My aim is to make "scheduler" able to wait for tasks to appear as half of the time there will be no tasks at all and they will be added from time to time.

Comment: The `Task.WaitAll` will wait till both `fileRequest` and `commonRequest` become empty after you have called `CompleteAdding()`, if there where no pending requests it would exit immediately. I only put it in to make a complete example console program. And I agree I would put any cancellation tokens and `IProgress` objects inside the wrapper that gets put in to the queue if you want individual job reporting and cancelability, you also would need your code in `ProcessWork` to cooperatively check to see if the current job has been canceled.

Comment: All that being said, can you show in code what kind of work you would be doing with these tasks? You may not want to use this approach and instead use something like IO Completion ports, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: The application is some kind of GUI tool for users to upload their work (images/vectors mostly) to some websites. There are many different web requests issued at pretty random manner (user decides when to start the process for every website, there are many websites and upload process is different for every website - there are multiple steps - authorization, uploading, filling forms, etc.).
So the single task will be some HTTP request (I am using HttpWebRequest with custom wrapper). Depending on site these requests can have very different parameters.

Comment: Most of the time next request for the same image upload job is started after previous is completed (it is pointless to try to upload image before authorization is completed, etc.) but this won't always be the case (sometimes I need to download like 100 image thumbnails from the site and I like to parallel it to multiple threads).

Comment: Regarding these blocking collections: will the tasks in them start running if I won't call CompleteAdding? If I got it right I should call this CompleteAdding every time I add next batch of requests (or a single request) and I want them to be executed?

Comment: Yes, what [`CompleteAdding()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does is in "normal operation" when you attempt to get data from the `BlockingCollection` and there is no work available `IEnumerator.MoveNext()` will block till data becomes available(That is why it is called **Blocking**Collection). Once you call `CompleteAdding()` instead of blocking when you call `IEnumerator.MoveNext()` it will return `false` signaling you have reached the end of the collection and the `Parallel.ForEach` will stop blocking which will allow the `Task` to end.

Comment: So it seems your solution will work for my case but I don't need to call CompleteAdding() and Task.WaitAll(). In this case I will be able to add tasks to any of the queues depending on their type and they will get executed as soon as possible while obeying the rules I described.
The last question I have is how to specify low priority queue max concurrency?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46037/discussion-between-scott-chamberlain-and-mephisto123)

Comment: I just realized there is no way to dynamically change max amount of concurrent low priority (short) tasks based on the fact the high priority (long) task is running. Or is there a way to do it?

Comment: I had to invent my own "wheel" and write that task scheduler on my own :( Will mark your answer as the solution though since there is no other answers. May be someone will find it useful.